# Setting up Exchange server 2013 in Azure VM with Server 2012

Tags: azure, exchange-server, server

I have a couple of questions relating to setting up exchange server on Azure.

Firstly, how would I estimate the approximate monthly cost of hosting my email server on Azure?

Secondly, is there a tutorial that provides steps for install and setup?

I assume it is something like
Create VM running Server 2012 essentials
Download Exchange server to folder on VM
Install exchange

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you will be unable to get any form of support if you have problems with your Exchange Server once operational as Microsoft does not support Exchange Server running on Azure (they would point you to Exchange Online as part of Office 365).

Also note that even if you do setup your mail server you will most likely suffer bounced messages from recipients as it's most likely the public IP of your Exchange server will be a member of the IP address ranges that most spam managers would rank low on the trust level.  This is why Microsoft partners with SendGrid for the purpose of mail delivery out of applications hosted in Azure.

Some cautionary reading: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/why-running-exchange-azure-unattractive-proposition

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a Calculator at [Windows Azure site](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines), which let you calculate the cost involved in hosting Server on Windows Azure.

To set up Exchange 2013 in Azure VM, follow the steps given below:

1. Configure the virtual networking settings (not mandatory)
2. Create a storage account
3. Provision a virtual machine from the Windows Azure Gallery and
   configure it as a Domain Controller
4. Provision the Exchange virtual machine using PowerShell
5. Install Exchange Server 2013

Please do let me know if there is any confusion.